# How to add new field to hr.employee.public [Odoo 14]

Tags: odoo-14

I'm a newbie to Odoo. I can add new field to hr.employee but fail on hr.employee.public. It shows

```
error psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column emp.onboarding_date does not exist.
```

Why Odoo cannot create new column in the case?

I would like to add onboarding_date to both hr.view_employee_form and hr.hr_employee_public_view_form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Odoo V13:

Inherit from `hr.employee.base` instead of `hr.employee`. Related [commit](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/commit/c9ca3761464413327d2beb697553a3ccd7eef4d1).